# What does 'Only a ReactOwner can have refs.' mean?

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple `react` component with a form in it:

```js
var AddAppts = React.createClass({
    handleClick: function() {
        var title = this.refs.title.getDOMNode().value;
        ....

        var appt = {
            heading: title
            ...
        }

        CalendarActions.addAppointment(appt);
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <label>Description</label>
                <input ref="title"></input>
                ...
            </div>
        );
    }
});
module.exports = AddAppts;
```

I am trying to `render` this component in another `react` component:

```js
  var AddAppt = require('./AddAppts');

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <AddAppt />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

but I get this error:

```js
 Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. This usually means that you're trying to add a ref to a component that doesn't have an owner (that is, was not created inside of another component's `render` method). Try rendering this component inside of a new top-level component which will hold the ref.
```

I have googled it, but cannot figure out what I need to do to fix this issue.

Comment: Those are 2 different files.  When I imported the file, I gave it a different name.

Comment: I tried to replicate what I think is your setup. Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/wmL2xvqn/) pretty close?

Comment: Could you also state which react version you are using? Have you figured out what the problem is?

Comment: Have you found the meaning of this error ?

Comment: I have not figured out the problem.  I am using `React 0.13.1`

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Has anyone found a meaning/solution?

Comment: In the meantime, Facebook has added a link to the error message: https://gist.github.com/jimfb/4faa6cbfb1ef476bd105. Make sure to have a look at the comments for possible solutions.

Answer (score 55):

This is FYI for people using react and redux-devtools who are getting OP's message. Your structure looks like

```
project
  client
  node_modules
    react
    redux-devtools
      node_modules
        react
```

The code in client will require the first react module; that in redux-devtools will require the other react. The react module keeps state and assumes it has all the state.

You get the OP's message because your state is split between the 2 react modules. This situation is what I believe @asbjornenge refers to.

I was bundling the client code with webpack, so I used that to handle the issue. You can force all `require` and `import` to always use the first react by adding the following to webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'react': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'react')
    },
    extensions: ['', '.js']
  },
  ...
);
```

I have not looked into what I would need to do if the situation occurred with unbundled code running on node.

Comment: Simplest solution I've seen so far considering how fragmented and messy the JS dev community is

Comment: You deserve a medal! A bad issue, really - sanity is back on.

Comment: Why do you need `extensions` property as well as resolve.alias?

Comment: FYI - I personally had to use process.cwd() instead of dirname, but this did work and is very useful. Cheers

Comment: It all depends where your webpack.config file is located @netpoetica. process.cwd() is likely correct more often than __dirname.

Comment: I _believe_ the empty string in extensions allowed requires of subdirectories e.g. react/lib/index . Sorry, its been a while.

Comment: This worked for me. I was developing a library locally and had it as a file dependency as such npm wasn't able to flatten the dependencies

Comment: Just fantastic. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 42):

I encountered this error when a component module I was using had it's own react dependency installed. So I was using multiple versions of React.

Make sure NOT to list react under `dependencies` in your `package.json`.
This is why we have `peerDependencies` ;-)

Comment: Ah! Thanks for this. I was accidentally compiling two versions of React in a test and coming up with this error. I'd never have found it by myself. Rookie mistake!

Comment: Aren't peer dependencies being removed in NPM 3.0? What then?

Comment: My problem is the order of the loading script. I load react-with-addons.js before react-dom.js. And the problem appeared. I doubt that there are some feature in react-with-addons.js :)

Comment: @JohnSz peerDependencies are not being removed, they will just warn instead of auto-installing. See https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6565#issuecomment-74971689.

Answer (score 16):

Just in case. Be aware of the React module name you are using (it is case-sensitive). I've got the same error when by coincidence I tried to `require` React dependency with different names in two separate modules.

```
//module1.js
var React = require('react');
...

//module2.js
var React = require('React');
....
```

It works and even renders something but the *Only a ReactOwner can have refs...* error appears.

Comment: You just save me! I've been digging around for 20 minutes going crazy. I read this and looked down at my editor. Sure enough, a big "require('React')" was staring right back at me.

Answer (score 3):

Rearranging the script resolved the issue.

**Wrong.**

```
<script src="./lib/react.js"></script>
<script src="./lib/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="./lib/react-with-addons.js"></script>
```

**Correct**

```
<script src="./lib/react.js"></script>
<script src="./lib/react-with-addons.js"></script>
<script src="./lib/react-dom.js"></script>
```

Reference https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-form/issues/107#issuecomment-150891680

Comment: Is including both `react` and `react-with-addons` necessary? Does not the latter include all the code of the former?

Answer (score 2):

I saw this error while developing a react module that was linked to a test project using [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link). Switching to a regular dependency solved the problem.

It seems that React doesn't like `npm link`.

Comment: What does 'switching to a regular dependency' mean?

Comment: `npm link` is a way to use a directory (via a symbolic link) in place of a dependency installed by `npm`. Removing the symbolic link and relaunching `npm install` fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is another situation.

I set the React as external library in the webpack.config.js and import react.js from cdnjs.

```
externals: {
  'react': 'React'
}
```

When I using an ui library depend on React,such as material-ui,react-bootstrap,this issue occurred.

Answer (score 0):

am writing with my old pen. make sure in your project root package.json move react dependency as early as possible. still you are getting issue? & if you are using npm modules and grunt task, you can add below clean task to remove inner components react(duplicates).

`clean: {
  react : ['node_modules/**/react','!node_modules/react']
},`

Answer (score 0):

I saw this error after I moved my `package.json` file up a level, so I had 2 `node_modules` directories in my project (one in `./node_modules` and another in `./web/node_modules`).  Removing the old directory fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me the reason for the same problem was that I've imported the `ReactDom` globally, as a property of the window object, like this:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
window.ReactDOM = ReactDOM
```

removing `window.ReactDOM = ReactDOM` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39405375/1817064), I was seeing this error while using a separate module that I had been developing in a separate directory using `yarn link`.

The solution was to run `yarn unlink module-name` in my project's working directory. I then removed `node_modules` and ran `yarn upgrade module-name` and `yarn` for good measure.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<input ref="title"></input>
```

Try this

```
<input ref={(title) => this.title = title}></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the given solutions worked for me, though they certainly helped show me where to look.

For some reason my project has two `node_modules` folders - one in the root directory and one a level up. I'm new to React so I don't know if this is normal or what. I'm just going with what Visual Studio gave me when I started a new project.

Anyway, I knew which module was causing the problem, and it happened to only exist in *one* of the `node_modules` folders.

I moved the problem module over to the other `node_modules` folder. Problem solved.