# How to avoid React loading twice with Webpack when developing

Tags: npm, reactjs, webpack

Given the following directory structure:

```
my-project
|
|-- node_modules
    |
    |-- react
    |-- module-x
        |
        |--node_modules
            |
            |--react
```

You can see both **my-project** and **module-x** require React.  I have the same problem as described on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519287/what-does-only-a-reactowner-can-have-refs-mean), but the suggestion is to remove react from the package.json dependencies.  I do that and it works fine, as long as no node_modules are installed in **module-x**, because Webpack will use React from **my-project**.  But if I'm in the process of developing **module-x** and the node_modules are installed, Webpack uses React from both **my-project** and **module-x**.

Is there a way I could have Webpack make sure only one instance of React is used, even though it's required on two separate levels?

I know I could keep **module-x** in a separate directory when developing, but it seems like I'd have to publish it and then install it in **my-project** to test it, and that's not very efficient.  I thought about `npm link`, but had no luck with it since it still has node_modules installed in **module-x**.

[This here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/105) sounds a lot like the same challenge I'm having, but it doesn't seem like `npm dedupe` or Webpack's dedupe option would work.  I'm probably not understanding some important detail.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

This issue usually arises when using `npm link`. A linked module will resolve its dependencies in its own module tree, which is different from the one of the module that required it. As such, the `npm link` command installs `peerDependencies` as well as `dependencies`.

You can use `resolve.alias` to force `require('react')` to resolve to your local version of React.

```js
resolve: {
  alias: {
    react: path.resolve('./node_modules/react'),
  },
},
```

Comment: I've spend half a day on this issue. Unfortunately, neither the error message in the browser nor the Webpack docs are very helpful. You have saved my day! Thanks!! 

Comment: This solution still causes webpack to assign different IDs to react that is referenced from an app and react that is referenced from a linked module. So multiple instances of react module created by webpack.

Comment: Saved me. Here are the docs: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias

Comment: React still gets imported multiple times with this, but react no longer throws an error, which is good enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 60):

If you don’t want to (or can’t) modify the project configuration, there is a more straightforward solution: just **`npm link` React itself back to your project:**

```
# link the component
cd my-app
npm link ../my-react-component

# link its copy of React back to the app's React
cd ../my-react-component
npm link ../my-app/node_modules/react
```

Comment: This can get messy. Libraries are one-to-many (one library installed in many apps), but this associates a library with only one app by linking that app's react folder to the library. So working with two apps at once isn't possible (like the library's example page and also the consumer app).

Comment: @MatthiasDailey any idea how to solve it if we have more projects?

Comment: @alek I've found yalc useful, and yarn workspaces if another solution if you use yarn.

Comment: This answer saved my day with a CRA (Create React App). The answer could be more easy to understand by adding resulting links with absolute paths.

Comment: If you use `yarn`:

`# link the component
cd my-app/node_modules/react
yarn link 

# link its copy of React back to the app's React
cd ../../../my-react-component
yarn link react`

Comment: Is this solution still valid if both libraries are using different versions of react?

Comment: @dan I have a shared component library that's used with two Create React App apps. Which should I link it to?

Comment: This is the recommended solution: https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#duplicate-react

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it's useful for others, the solutions suggested above didn't work for me, I had to perform the following steps to solve it:

**In the library**:

1. Setup the libraries that are generating issues as `peerDependencies` in the `package.json` instead of `dependencies` or `devDependencies`, e.g. in my case `react`:

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "react": "^16.8.6",
  ...
}
```

2. run `npm install`
3. build the library (in my case, with a `rollup -c` npm script

**In my main app**:

4. change the version of my library to point to my local project with a  relative path in `package.json`, e.g.

```
"dependencies": {
  "my-library": "file:../../libraries/my-library",
  ...
}
```

5. Add `resolve.symlinks = false` to my main app's webpack configuration
6. Add `--preserve-symlinks-main` and `--preserve-symlinks` to my `package.json` start script, e.g:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "set WEBPACK_CONFIG_FILE=all&& webpack",
  "start": "set WEBPACK_CONFIG_FILE=all&& webpack && node --preserve-symlinks-main --preserve-symlinks dist/server.js",
}
```

7. run `npm install`
8. run `npm run start`

Answer (score 0):

In the same vein as the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31170775/4391298) here's how you can achieve the desired outcome with [Craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco):

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: config => {
      config = {
        ...config,
        resolve: {
          ...config.resolve,
          alias: {
            ...config.resolve.alias,
            'react': path.resolve('./node_modules/react'),
          },
        },
      }
      // console.log(config)
      return config
    },
  },
}
```

It's important to note you can't just pass `resolve` as a key, you have to do your own deep merge using the `configure` callback.