# Export `react-router` Redirect from shared component library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, react-router

I have a shared (React) component library that I'm building. There is a `PrivateRoute` component that I am wanting to include. However, when I import the component from the module library into another application, I get an error:

> Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Redirect> outside a <Router>

The `PrivateRoute` component wraps the `react-router/Route` component with authentication logic and redirects unauthenticated requests to login:

**component-library**

```js
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router';
/* ... */

class PrivateRoute extends Component {
  /* ... */
  render() {
    const {
      component: Comp, authState, loginPath, ...rest
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props => authState === SIGNED_IN ? (
          <Comp {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: loginPath,
            }}
          />
        )}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

I then import the component into a separate (React) project:

**create-react-app**

```js
import { Router } from 'react-router';
import { PrivateRoute } from 'component-library';
/* ... */

class App extends Component {
  // "history" is passed in via props from the micro frontend controller.
  /* ... */

  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={this.props.history}>
        {/* ... */}
        <PrivateRoute path="/protected" component={ProtectedView} />
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

This will work as expected if the `PrivateRoute` component is defined in the *create-react-app* application. However, moving this component to the shared library results in the error.

I have tried building the library with webpack output `libraryTarget` set to *commonjs2*. But, I've also tried *umd*. I've also tried with Rollup. All with the same results.

**webpack.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/'),
    publicPath: '',
    filename: '[name].js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
  },
  //...
};
```

My assumption is that the issue is with building the component library as the Invariant error is thrown when `Redirect` is unable to find the `RouterContext`. Although the library builds without errors, it seems that importing compiled/built code is a problem.

Could also be two instances of React causing an issue with the Context API. However, `react-router` is not using the Context API. It's using the `mini-create-react-context` polyfill.

Any thoughts or ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Where you are importing Router from ?

Comment: Importing Router from 'react-router'. 'react-router' is a production dependency in the component library. So, the 'create-react-app' does not list 'react-router' as a dependency, but imports the Router from 'react-router' and PrivateRoute from the component library.

Comment: Is there a way to get a sandbox that reproduces this? I've tried at https://codesandbox.io/s/a-simple-react-router-v4tutorial-stnxs but I can't manage to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did finally discover the issue which had little to do with `react-router` and more with `React`. I found that this error would only show in local development because the `component-library` was linked via `npm link`.

The resolution came from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38818358/715597

The solution in my case was to link React and React Router in the component library to the applications reference of React and React Router:

```bash
# link the component library
cd my-app
npm link ../component-library

# link its copy of React back to the app's React
cd ../component-library
npm link ../my-app/node_modules/react
npm link ../my-app/node_modules/react-router
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to import router (assuming you're using V4) from react-router-dom, eg:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
```

> In v4, react-router exports the core components and functions.
>   react-router-dom exports DOM-aware components, like <Link> (which
>   renders an <a>) and <BrowserRouter> (which interacts with the
>   browser's window.history ).
>
> react-router-dom re-exports all of react-router's exports, so you only
>   need to import from react-router-dom in your project.

Ref: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4648#issuecomment-284479720

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm using `Router` because I have a unique situation where I have to define the history with `createBrowserHistory` (much like `BrowserRouter`). We have a micro frontend architecture and the history is shared between the registered applications to maintain state.

Comment: Yes but to manage router render you need anyway react-router-dom, mate

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do it using a function

```
if(authState === SIGNED_IN){
   return <Route
        {...rest}
        render={<Comp {...props} />
        />
}else{
   // here you can use window.location 
   // or 
   // render a different component (which shows unauthorized or something you want)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you only needed to remove dependency "react-router-dom": "5.0.0" from package.json to fix the error.