# Link react versions between linked library and workspace application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, npm-link

I'm developing a React library for my common used components. In my root folder where there is:

- my rollup config and my `src/` folder containing my library. When it's build, the bundle files (ES, CJS and UMD) are in the `dist/` folder.
- my workspace: a simple `parcel` bundled app where there is an independent `package.json`. In this `package.json`, myLib is in **dependencies** and I linked it.

When I want to use myLib in the workspace I import it like this: `import { Button } from 'myLib'`.

Here, everything seems to be okay. But in a component I'm using a hook and I have this error:

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

It seems there's two copies of React, `npm ls react` returns:

```
└─┬ myLib@1.0.0 invalid
  └── react@16.8.6  extraneous
```

I tried to link react and react-dom between `myLib/` and `workspace/` **node_modules** but it never works and this error is still here.

---

**TLDR;**

Here's my file tree:

```
myLib
│   package.json
│   rollup.config.js
│
└───dist/
│
└───src/
│   │   **
│
└───workspace
│   │   package.json
│   │   index.js
```

To link myLib to workspace: I go to `myLib/` and I do `yarn link` then I go to `workspace/` and I do `yarn link myLib`

react and react-dom are **peerDependencies** in `myLib`and **devDependencies** in `workspace/`

---

Oh course I already looked here:

- https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html
- https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991
- https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15315
- https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15628

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution for this issue is actually explained in the [react doc](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html):

> This problem can also come up when you use npm link or an equivalent. In that case, your bundler might “see” two Reacts — one in application folder and one in your library folder. Assuming myapp and mylib are sibling folders, one possible fix is to run `npm link ../myapp/node_modules/react` from mylib. This should make the library use the application’s React copy.

Another solution is to use [lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) (with [hoisting](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/blob/master/doc/hoist.md)).

Answer (score 9):

Here is a simple solution that works with [yarn](/questions/tagged/yarn) and [npm](/questions/tagged/npm):

```sh
cd /your-library/node_modules/react
yarn link
cd /your-library/node_modules/react-dom
yarn link
cd /your-app
yarn link react
yarn link react-dom
```

Ensure that `your-library` has React version compatible with `your-app`.

Alternatively, if you are using [webpack](/questions/tagged/webpack), just configure alias:

```js
alias: {
  react: path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/react'),
  'react-dom': path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/react-dom'),
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer that worked for me here: [How to avoid React loading twice with Webpack when developing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169760/how-to-avoid-react-loading-twice-with-webpack-when-developing/38818358#38818358)

I spent a bit of time with this problem, yet the answer was simple. If you are having multiple versions of React, you have to go to your workspace and link to the version of React in myLib.