# Using react external components and webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I use webpack and have a simple react application, where I want to use [react-autosuggest](https://github.com/moroshko/react-autosuggest) component. When I want to use this component in my application I get error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. This usually means that you're trying to add a ref to a component that doesn't have an owner (that is, was not created inside of another component's `render` method). Try rendering this component inside of a new top-level component which will hold the ref.
```

**index.jsx**

```
var React = require('react')
var Autosuggest = require('react-autosuggest')

var autoCompleteItems = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6'];

function getSuggestions(input, callback) {
  const escapedInput = utils.escapeRegexCharacters(input.trim());
  const lowercasedInput = input.trim().toLowerCase();
  const suburbMatchRegex = new RegExp('\\b' + escapedInput, 'i');
  const suggestions = autoCompleteItems
    .filter( suburbObj => suburbMatchRegex.test(suburbObj.suburb) )
    .sort( (suburbObj1, suburbObj2) =>
      suburbObj1.suburb.toLowerCase().indexOf(lowercasedInput) -
      suburbObj2.suburb.toLowerCase().indexOf(lowercasedInput)
    )
    .slice(0, 7)
    .map( suburbObj => suburbObj.suburb );

  setTimeout(() => callback(null, suggestions), 300);
}

class SuggestWrapper extends React.Component {
  render () {

    var inputId = 'input-example';

    const inputAttributes = {
      id: inputId,
      className: "form-control",
      defaultValue: '',
      placeholder: this.props.propertyName
    };

    return (

      <Autosuggest suggestions={getSuggestions}
                   inputAttributes={inputAttributes}
                   ref={ () => { document.getElementById(inputId).focus(); } } />

    );
  }
}


class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <SuggestWrapper />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "react_modules",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run serve | npm run dev",
    "serve": "./node_modules/.bin/http-server -p 8080",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server -d --progress --colors --port 8090"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^5.8.24",
    "babel-loader": "^5.3.2",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.5",
    "bower-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.8",
    "css-loader": "^0.18.0",
    "events": "^1.0.2",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^0.8.2",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.4",
    "http-server": "^0.8.0",
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.10.5",
    "less": "^2.5.1",
    "less-loader": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "node-sass": "^3.3.2",
    "object-assign": "^4.0.1",
    "path": "^0.11.14",
    "react": "^0.13.3",
    "react-autosuggest": "^1.18.3",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "sass-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.12.3",
    "svg-sprite-loader": "0.0.3",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.6",
    "webpack": "^1.12.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.10.1"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const BowerWebpackPlugin = require("bower-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.jsx',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    sourceMapFilename: "[file].map",
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8090/assets'
  },
  debug: true,
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js[x]?$/,
      loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
      exclude: /node_modules/
    }, {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap', 'sass?sourceMap']
    }, {
      test: /\.less$/,
      loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap', 'less?sourceMap']
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loaders: ['style', 'css']
    }, {
      test: /\.woff$/,
      loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
    }, {
      test: /\.woff2$/,
      loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff2"
    }, {
      test: /\.(eot|ttf|svg|gif|png)$/,
      loader: "file-loader"
    }]
  },
  plugins: [
    new BowerWebpackPlugin()
  ],
  externals: {
    'react': 'React'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>App</title>
    <!-- include react -->
    <script src="./node_modules/react/dist/react-with-addons.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <!-- this is where the root react component will get rendered -->
    </div>
    <!-- include the webpack-dev-server script so our scripts get reloaded when we make a change -->
    <!-- we'll run the webpack dev server on port 8090, so make sure it is correct -->
    <script src="http://localhost:8090/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>
    <!-- include the bundle that contains all our scripts, produced by webpack -->
    <!-- the bundle is served by the webpack-dev-server, so serve it also from localhost:8090 -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8090/assets/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519287/what-does-only-a-reactowner-can-have-refs-mean) post and add:

```
alias: {
      'react': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'react')
    },
```

but it didn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error can happen when you have two (or more) copies of React in your bundle. Try running `npm ls react` to see if this is happening. Then you might try `npm dedupe` (or upgrade to npm 3.x. <s>It's still beta but it's pretty stable and</s> it dedupes automatically). You really need all the packages you use to be compatible with the version of React you're using, of course, since having multiple Reacts causes errors (and a bloated bundle!).

Edit: just noticed you have a script tag for React **and** you're importing it. Taking out the react script tag might be all you need to fix the problem!

Comment: Thank you for response, yes I know that I probably get this error because I have in my bundle 2 copies of react, but i don't know how to deal with it. When I type `npm ls react` I get only `react@0.13.3`. I tried `npm dedupe` but nothing happen. When I tried to remove `script` tag in `index.html` I get error React is not defined.

Comment: Why are you declaring React as an external in your webpack config?

Comment: I think that's the problem here. Declaring as external means "fetch it out of a global variable." That's why *your* code is reliant on the script tag being there; *your* code is using the script tag copy of React, while react-autosuggest is using the React installed through npm. I would solve this by removing the script tag and removing the "externals" section of webpack.config.js.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks @AdamDiCarlo

Answer (score 3):

The explanation to your error is contained in the error message:

> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. **This usually means that you're trying to add a ref to a component that doesn't have an owner (that is, was not created inside of another component's `render` method)**. Try rendering this component inside of a new top-level component which will hold the ref.

You cannot add a `ref` to a top level component, as you are doing in your `SuggestWrapper`:

```
<Autosuggest suggestions={getSuggestions}
               inputAttributes={inputAttributes}
               ref={ () => { document.getElementById(inputId).focus(); } } />
```

To achieve what you want, you may use the [`componentDidMount` lifecycle hook:](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount)

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.getElementById(inputId).focus();
}
```

From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount):

> At this point in the lifecycle, the component has a DOM representation which you can access via React.findDOMNode(this). The componentDidMount() method of child components is invoked before that of parent components.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I changed my code but still get the same error. [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/npqhnw5y)