# React refs on production build responding with addComponentAsRefTo

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my component, with ref

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export default class Comp1 extends Component {

render() {
  return (
    <span >
      <span ref="someRef">
        <input type='text'/>
      </span>
    </span>
  );
}
```

which responds as expected on development env, but when I build with `production` env, then the following error comes

> invariant.js:38 Uncaught Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's `render` method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded (details: https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/refs-must-have-owner.html).

I am really stuck with this error. Has anyone faced similar issue??
With react v15.0.1

According to official documentation for this error, there can be two reasons, **Invalid Refs** and **Multiple copies of react**.
Here is my `npm ls react`

`└── react@15.2.1`

And, the following is `npm ls | grep react`

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does 'Only a ReactOwner can have refs.' mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519287/what-does-only-a-reactowner-can-have-refs-mean)

Comment: Thanks for giving the link for similar issue. Please read the updated section

Comment: I had the same issue with the error only showing in production builds. It turned out that after a refactor I was using the same string ref over and over again while mapping over an array. Removing the ref also fixed the error.