# React how can i add 'ref' to dom out of render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

the exmcode is here

```
mines[i] = (
  <p key = {i} ref = {i}></p>
  );
  .....
  render(
      return(
          {mines}
      )
  )
```

when i render it on my page ,

**(actually i added a click
function first,the "mines" changed when i click the button)**

the browser call error

> addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's render method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded.

how can i do

Comment: Try wrapping `{mines}` into a div and add ref to this `div`

Comment: Please take a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519287/what-does-only-a-reactowner-can-have-refs-mean

Comment: If you want to display a list of items you should follow the official docs, there you´ll find everything you need, you display a list you have to use "map" in ordner to loop through your items
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

Cant you put this inside render, but before return? Something like that:

```
  render(
      mines[i] = (
        <p key = {i} ref = {i}></p>
      );
      return(
        <div className="wrapper">
          {mines}
        </div>
      )
  )
```

Comment: maybe it's one of the solution,but i want to put it outside if could . btw thank you

Comment: Try to use a unique string to create your ref name: ref = { 'test-' + i }