# react-preloader-icon with redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm new to react/redux and trying to use this preloader lib with react/redux:
https://github.com/UYEONG/react-preloader-icon

I get this error in browser console when trying to use it:

*Uncaught Error: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's `render` method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded...*

I use it in a container component **Books'** render method...

- Why am I getting this error?
- What does it mean?
- What is the correct way of using the preloader component?

  ```
  class Books extends React.Component {

    constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);
      this.redirectToAddBookPage = this.redirectToAddBookPage.bind(this);
    }

    createBookRow(book, index) {
      return <div key={index}>{ book.title }</div>;
    }

    redirectToAddBookPage() {
      browserHistory.push('/book');
    }

    render() {
      const {books} = this.props;
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Books</h1>
          <input type="submit"
                 value="Add new book"
                 className="btn btn-primary"
                 onClick={this.redirectToAddBookPage}/>

          <PreloaderIcon
            type={ICON_TYPE.OVAL}
            size={32}
            strokeWidth={3}
            strokeColor="#F0AD4E"
            duration={800}
          />

          <BookList books={books}/>
        </div>
      );
    }

  }

  Books.propTypes = {
    books: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  };

  function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
      books: state.books
    };
  }

  export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Books);
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was loading react multiple times so state was shared between multiple instances of react... I solved it by adding this to my `webpack.config.js` file, forcing the app to only use the 'primary' dependency from `node_modules/react` folder:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    'react': path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'react')
  }
}
```

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519287/what-does-only-a-reactowner-can-have-refs-mean).

Answer (score 1):

As the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/refs-must-have-owner.html) state this would occur if you are adding a ref an element outside the render method.
or it could occur if you have multiple copies of react present.
perhaps try running

rm -rf node_modules  && npm install